# Ruby gsub case insensitive not working as expected

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a problem with a regex I am using for gsub. The part of my program that is problematic loads two text files: one that it will work on, and another one as an array of abbreviations. The thing is that I want to delete any `\n`s that are directly before or directly after any of the abbreviations (I keep them separate on purpose). This is not really a problem and my solution works, BUT the abbreviations might be in upper or lower case, while my list contains only one version of each (mixed lower and upper case).

The function works fine, except for the upper/lower case issue. I added the `::IGNORECASE` to the regex in gsub, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Below is my function that gets an array of strings:

```
def generateRegexes(some_array)
    matchRegexPrefix = Regexp.new("\n(%{abbrevReplace})" % {
        abbrevReplace: Regexp.union(some_array)
    }, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
    matchRegexSuffix = Regexp.new("(%{abbrevReplace})\n" % {
        abbrevReplace: Regexp.union(some_array)
    }, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
    return [matchRegexPrefix, matchRegexSuffix]
end
```

And here is how I call the function:

```
regexAbbrev = generateRegexes listOfAbbreviations
stringToBeFixed.gsub!(regexAbbrev [0], " \\1")
stringToBeFixed.gsub!(regexAbbrev [1], "\\1 ")
```

What I would like to happen is that my method would match `\nAbbrev` or `Abbrev\n` regardless of case and replace the \n with a space while keeping the abbreviation in the original form.

---

Edit: supplying requested information (don't mind the Polish language gibberish).

Portion of the input:

```
Fum, u, lm. y 1. † dym, wyziew, para: Fumy do głowy z picia biją.
Troc. 2. † pachnidło, perfumy, kosmetyk.
Zdr. † Fumik. <Łć. fumus>
× Fungować, uje, ował sprawować urząd, wypełniać obowiązki: Funguje jako poseł królewski.
Szuj. <Łć. fungi>
Funkcja, i, lm. e 1. sprawa załatwiania. Zdr.
Funkcyjka. <Łć. functio>
```

Portion of the abbreviation list:

```
Troc.
Szuj.
zdr.
```

Expected output:

```
Fum, u, lm. y 1. † dym, wyziew, para: Fumy do głowy z picia biją. Troc. 2. † pachnidło, perfumy, kosmetyk. Zdr. † Fumik. <Łć. fumus>
× Fungować, uje, ował sprawować urząd, wypełniać obowiązki: Funguje jako poseł królewski. Szuj. <Łć. fungi>
Funkcja, i, lm. e 1. sprawa załatwiania. Zdr. Funkcyjka. <Łć. functio>
```

The output I actually get (half of what I want):

```
Fum, u, lm. y 1. † dym, wyziew, para: Fumy do głowy z picia biją. Troc. 2. † pachnidło, perfumy, kosmetyk.
Zdr. † Fumik. <Łć. fumus>
× Fungować, uje, ował sprawować urząd, wypełniać obowiązki: Funguje jako poseł królewski. Szuj. <Łć. fungi>
Funkcja, i, lm. e 1. sprawa załatwiania. Zdr.
Funkcyjka. <Łć. functio>
```

Comment: Could you provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Sample input, expected output would be very helpful, too.

Comment: Done as requested :)

Comment: Well, did you try using inline option `(?i)`? E.g. `"(?i)\n(%{abbrevReplace})"`?

Comment: @stribizhev: Wouldn't work. You get `(?i)\n((?-mix:foo|bar))`, where `Regexp#union` explicitly overrides the case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing that you can do instead of using `Regexp.union` is to manually construct your Regexp source:

```
pattern = some_array.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join('|')
text.gsub(/\n(#{pattern})/i, ' \1').gsub(/(#{pattern})\n/i, '\1 ')
```

Output:

```
Fum, u, lm. y 1. † dym, wyziew, para: Fumy do głowy z picia biją. Troc. 2. † pachnidło, perfumy, kosmetyk. Zdr. † Fumik. <Łć. fumus>
× Fungować, uje, ował sprawować urząd, wypełniać obowiązki: Funguje jako poseł królewski. Szuj. <Łć. fungi>
Funkcja, i, lm. e 1. sprawa załatwiania. Zdr. Funkcyjka. <Łć. functio>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, neat — didn't know this trick. Do you mind telling me what does the `&` do there?

Comment: @iyoossaev: It converts a `Proc`, as returned by `Object#method`, into a block, as expected by `Enumerable#map`. It is functionally equivalent to `.map { |w| Regexp.escape(w) }`

Comment: Funnily enough, I think I understand that answer… Thanks! =]

Answer (score 1):

[`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) doesn't have a way to specify options unlike `Regexp.new`. The returned regular expressions therefore has no enabled options:

```
Regexp.union(%w(a b c)).options # => 0
```

This can be also observed if the result is converted to a string with [`Regexp#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s) like `String#%` does (note the *explicit* option off extended group):

```
Regexp.union(%w(a b c)).to_s # => "(?-mix:a|b|c)"
```

This means options will be inherited when this method is called as your implicitly does.

You could call [`Regexp#source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-source) on the regular expression compiled by `Regexp.union`. Its return value doesn't contain the option off extended group stuff (`?-mix:` and `)`:

```
Regexp.union(%w(a b c)).source # => "a|b|c"
```

Comment: Okay, this is interesting — didn't know that about Regexp.union. What I tried to do just now is
`matchRegexPrefix = Regexp.new("\n(%{abbrevReplace})" % {
        abbrevReplace: Regexp.union(some_array)
    }).source`
and then:
`stringToBeFixed.gsub!(/#{regexAbbrev[0]}/i, " \\1")`
But it still doesn't work the way I want it to work.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that mixing will not work after conversion to a normal regex? Funny think though, but the regex I get still contains this `?-mix:` part.

Comment: @iyoossaev: Your new code has the same issue: regexp with no options (where did the `Regexp::IGNORECASE` go?). Just add `.source` (twice) to the code in your Q and you should get the expected output.

Comment: I just reverted to my original code and just appended the both Regexp.new instances with .source: `matchRegexPrefix = Regexp.new("\n(%{skrotReplace})" % {
  skrotReplace: Regexp.union(jakas_tablica)
 }, Regexp::IGNORECASE).source` No effect, still matches case sensitive

Comment: @iyoossaev: `Regexp.union(jakas_tablica).source` (as shown in my answer) and remove the other `.source`.

Comment: I only now noticed how stupid was what I tried to do. Works like a charm now. Thanks a bunch for the explanation — you are my favorite person today :)